# What is meant by node id in windmill workflow engine and how to get it

Tags: workflow, workflow-engine, windmill

I am using Windmill workflow engine to create jobs and run them

I am running jobs asynchronously.

For that I first create a job and then that returns me a job-id and I use this job-id to get the result.

In the API documentation to get the result of a job in Windmill workflow engine (https://app.windmill.dev/openapi.html#/operations/resultById).

They mention node id as a url param, but they haven't described what it is and how to get it.

While creating a job using https://app.windmill.dev/openapi.html#/operations/runScriptByPath they return a job id but there is no node id .

I have tried searching for node id on web and on windmill platform as well but did not find any description of same.